# Powershell script to return all logged on users on domain

Tags: powershell, domain

I have a powershell script that returns all of the users logged into all of the machines on the domain.
For some reason, it works fine when ran as an individual line

```
query session console /server:computer1
```

But, in my code that loops all the computernames in a file, I keep getting invalid parameters errors.

```
$cred = Get-Credential -Credential 'domain\administrator'
$CompName = Get-Content "C:\temp\comps.txt"

foreach($Comp in $CompName)
{
    query session console /server:$comp -Credential $cred 
}
```

The C:\temp\comps.txt looks like this:

```
Computer1
Computer2
Computer3
```

I cannot seem to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: query session does not require -credential ... try removing that part (the whole -credential $cred) and run without.

Comment: Without it, I get access denied.

Comment: use this: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-LoggedOnUser-Gathers-7cbe93ea like this: `'server01','server02' | .\Get-LoggedOnUser.ps1` - does that work?

Answer (score 1):

What happened to your script:

- Access denied - Your query session (under your current username) does not have admin rights over the "remote computer".
- invalid parameters errors - because "query session" does not accept -Credential as its command switch.

Assuming you have username and credentials (with admin rights) that works on the other computer - you need to run your powershell (and query session) in conjunction with runas.

> Example: runas /user:user@domain "powershell.exe codeabove.ps1"

This will allow your powershell session running as that user@domain, which will then run the powershell script and run the query session as that user@domain. Assuming that user@domain has access to the remote computer, it will return the output you need.